# C# Защита памяти в Assembly.Load()

Tags: c#, защита

Я пытаюсь сделать протектор для программ на C#. Суть его в том, что защищаемый файл переводится в байты и шифруется. Затем в другой программе, которая расшифровывает этот массив из ресурсов, я произвожу запуск сборки через `Assembly.Load(DecryptModule(Properties.Resources.Protected,"Pass"))`. Проблема заключается в незащищённой памяти, которая используется для `Assembly.Load()` и я могу снять эту защиту в 1 клик обычным дампом. Как можно защитить память(Если это возможно), которая используется для `Assembly.Load()` ?

Comment: Невозможно. Точка.

Comment: посмотри, может такие библиотеки уже существуют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Механизма защиты отдельной управляемой сборки в .NET не существует. В Windows, однако, существуют другие механизмы защиты памяти.

1. Начиная с Windows 10, [Trusted execution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/trusted-execution) позволяет создавать изолированные области памяти, так что доступ к данным в такой области может быть получен только кодом, загруженным в эту же область. Требует аппаратной поддержки со стороны процессора (например, Intel Software Guard Extensions).
2. Для антивирусных приложений, начиная с Windows 8.1 существует механизм [защищенных сервисов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-), который ограничивает доступ к памяти целого процесса. Любые модули, загружаемые в защищенный сервис, должны быть подписаны специальным сертификатом.
3. Приложения для обработки звука или видео, начиная с Windows Vista, могут использовать Windows Media Foundation, который в целях защиты авторских прав также предоставляет похожий функционал (см. [Protected Media Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/protected-media-path))
4. Когда вышеперечисленное не применимо, приложение может попытаться защитится теми же методами, которыми действует вредоносное ПО: инжекция DLL в во все процессы и перехват вызовов функций работы с памятью (ReadProcessMemory и др.). Антивирусы в старых версиях Windows действуют именно так. Однако, этот метод очень ненадежен, ведь если в системе две программы пытаются применить его одновременно, они входят в конфликт и результат непредсказуем.

В общем, если вам нужна реальная защита, как минимум нужно переходить к использованию неуправляемого кода. Также, можно всегда вынести критичный код в удаленный сервис (думаю, это единственный реальный способ защиты, когда секретным является сам код).